# Mongoose bulk insert sometimes inserts twice (causing E11000 duplicate error)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line) and a bulk insert, I'm looping through my CSV to get my records into my collections.

It appears that it's "too fast", perhaps. The same records are sometimes being saved twice.

The trimmed-down version: (my actual function is very abstract for usability and super long)

```
var bulk = ThisCollection.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
lr = new LineByLineReader('myfile.csv');
lr.on("line", function (line) {
  lr.pause();           
  line = CSVtoArray(line); //custom function parses line of CSV
  var saveObj = mapObj(line); //custom function matches line values to object in appropriate format for schema
  bulk.insert(saveObj);
  lr.resume();
})

lr.on("end", function(){
  bulk.execute(function(err){
    //getting the below error logged here
  });
});
```

Please note that `_id` keys are being generated automatically - I am ***not*** creating these myself in any way. They do not yet exist on the `saveObj` when it is passed into `bulk.insert()`.

When I do this, I am consistently getting a

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.locations.$_id_ dup key: {: ObjectId(\'5660a055e6d1c8400e9c933e\') }
```

on the 82nd record.

@robertklep identified the issue. We tried a `bulk.insert(Object.assign({}, saveObj))`. This eliminated the issue but was *incredibly slow*.

Anyone else seen this sort of behavior, or have a solid solution?

Comment: Stop using `asdlfkjasdflkjasdflkjasdlfkj` as a predefined `_id` for your documents?

Comment: @robertklep The ID is generated automatically. I didn't copy-paste so I just made up some keyboard cat.

Comment: `$_id_` is the index that's used for the `_id` properties of your documents. Those have to be unique. Can you post the code where you insert the documents into the database?

Comment: @robertklep Updated, but it's a very straightforward bulk operation. I'll also point out that I have several other collections using this same methodology (I actually have a very abstract function this lives in that I use across several collections), some collections containing millions of records, and I have not had this issue until just now with this particular collection.

Comment: @robertklep It's definitely a behavior issue with `bulk` but I'm uncertain why.

Comment: How are you looping over your data? Can you doublecheck to see if the documents you're inserting don't happen to have a `_id` property (even though you don't set it yourself)?

Comment: @robertklep I did - I have a function that takes the CSV and matches the values in each line to an object, then I pass each object into the bulk insert. I tried logging them right before passing them to the insert function, and they absolutely do not have an _id field (except for the time I tried setting one manually).

Comment: Just for giggles, instead of inserting the document directly, can you try and see if this works: `bulk.insert(Object.assign({}, doc))` (in other words, create a shallow clone of the document before inserting it).

Comment: @robertklep Did... it was crazy slow, but it worked.

Comment: I think there's some weird aliasing going on, where documents that are being inserted are pointing to the same object. It depends on how exactly your CSV-to-bulk-insert loop is implemented.

Comment: @robertklep Yeah I'm going to have to rewrite the entire OP, it was not even close to the actual issue. It's going to take a while.

Comment: @robertklep updated the OP.

Comment: My guess is that `mapObj()` may be the cause. Also, I can recommend [`node-csv`](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv) for CSV-parsing.

Comment: @robertklep I was trying to figure that out, and it sets up the insert for all 40k records in a few seconds. But those objects are being created inside the closure. It really shouldn't be able to jump on it twice, everything is synchronous as far as I know.

Comment: It can be something as devious as an undeclared variable (which gets hoisted to module/global level and reused).